# How to change form action in datasource

Tags: datasource, smartgwt

I'm using SmartGwt's RestDataSource for interacting with a non java, non smart gwt back end. I have a a ListGrid which fetches and updates it's data using GET. This sometimes fails because of the size of the URL. How can I change it to use POST?